# How do I find out and add necessary extra fonts to wine?

Tags: linux, fonts, wine

I'm trying to use [Balsamiq Mockups under Wine](https://support.balsamiq.com/installation/linux/)

It *kind* of works.

This is what it **should look like** (running on a Mac):

[image: Balsamiq on a Mac]

Here's what it **does look like** (running under Wine on Arch Linux):
[image]

(ignore the size differences, that's just resolution of the monitors)

I'm almost 100% certain that the problem with not being able to see anything is that I must not have a font setup. But I'm not sure how to find that font, and once I've got it, where to put it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found it!

I had already installed `winetricks`, but if you don't have it:

```
# pacman -S winetricks
```

Then install corefonts:

```
$ winetricks corefonts
```

And voila!

[image: now, with more corefonts!]